# Is the Content-Type header appropriate for any HTTP verb other than PUT or POST?

Tags: python, http, rest, content-type

I'm trying out the REST API of the CollectionSpace software, and noticed that sending it a Content-Type header as part of a GET request results in the following error:

```
HTTP Status 415 - Cannot consume content type
```

Both of the python REST client libraries I've tried, restclient on github and python-rest-client on google code, do send a Content-Type header when making GET requests.

My understanding from reviewing http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html is that clients should only send Content-Type headers on POST and PUT requests. Is that correct?

The fact that both of these libraries do sent the header makes me think that servers typically ignore it, rather than return a client error code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although not explicitly outlined in the spec, one could make some inferences. [Section 7.2.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.2.1) states

> Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an
>   entity-body SHOULD include a
>   Content-Type header field defining the
>   media type of that body.

That's pretty obvious, and makes sense. Given that, we can have a look at [Section 9](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9) (Method Definitions) to see which ones mention that they'd possibly have an entity in the request body. Three of them mention it:

#### OPTIONS

> If the OPTIONS request includes an
>   entity-body (as indicated by the
>   presence of Content-Length or
>   Transfer-Encoding)...

#### POST

> ...used to request that the origin
>   server accept the entity enclosed in
>   the request...

#### PUT

> ...requests that the enclosed entity
>   be stored under the supplied
>   Request-URI

And one method specificially disallows entities, **TRACE**:

> A TRACE request MUST NOT include an
>   entity.

In reality you could send any method (except TRACE) with an entity in the body and a Content-Type header. However, per the spec, I wouldn't expect the server to do anything with it unless it were one of the three methods above.

---

I would also say that the software you're using that responds with the HTTP Status 415 is in violation of the specification.

[Section 4.3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.3) says:

> ...if the request method does not
>   include defined semantics for an
>   entity-body, then the message-body
>   SHOULD be ignored when handling the
>   request.

Since the spec doesn't include defined semantics for an entity body with a GET request, the server should ignore it.

Additionally if no entity was provided in the request, and the Content-Length is zero (assuming the Transfer-Encoding header is not set and is not "identity"), the server should not try to consume an entity, regardless of of the request method or whether or not there's a Content-Type header present. This can be backed up by the order of precedence for determining the message length described in [Section 4.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4).

Comment: Missed those extra sections of the spec. Very helpful, thanks! Will file a bug report referring here.

Comment: The Content-Type header field describes the media type of the payload. If there is no payload, as in GET, it's incorrect to send it.

Comment: @Julian - I agree that it really *shouldn't* be sent if there's no entity. I looked at the spec again to see if I could find anywhere where it's explicitly disallowed and couldn't. At best, the spec only *implies* that it shouldn't be sent with the [definition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) of `Content-Type`: *"indicates the media type of the entity-body sent to the recipient"*. Do you know of anywhere in the spec that's more concrete about it? In any case, if there's no entity, it's advisable to just not send a `Content-Type`.

Answer (score 2):

415 Cannot consume content type

This problem happens if the REST Resource has @Consumes suggesting to accept a particular MIME Type. To fix this set the correct "Accept" Header in the Request/Resource call along with "Content-Type" header.  For MockHttpRequest from RESTEasy it can be done simply as

request.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
request.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);